# How to pause and resume a CountDown Timer in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer, countdown

I have developed a CountDown Timer with ProgressBar it working fine but I am not sure how to pause and resume the timer when I click fab_play_pause button. please i need help, thank you so much

This is my code:

```
public class StandingSideStretch extends Fragment {

View rootView;
private TextView timer;
private FloatingActionButton fab_play_pause, fab_next, fab_back;
private ProgressBar mProgress;
MyCountDownTimer myCountDownTimer;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

private final long startTime = 60 * 1000;
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
private ObjectAnimator animation;

private static final String PLAY_ICON = "playIcon";
private static final String PAUSE_ICON = "pauseImage";


public StandingSideStretch() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_standing_side_stretch, container, false);

    setFabs();

    timer = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    timer.setText("60's");

    return rootView;
}

private void setFabs(){
    fab_play_pause = (FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_play_pause);
    fab_back = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_back);
    fab_next = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_next);

    fab_play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp);
    fab_play_pause.setTag(PLAY_ICON);
    fab_play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String tag = (String) view.getTag();

            if (view.getTag() == PLAY_ICON){

                fab_play_pause.setTag(PAUSE_ICON);
                fab_play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_24dp);
                timerHasStarted = true;

                countDownTimer.start();

                Resources res = getResources();
                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar_drawable);
                final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
                mProgress.setProgress(0);   // Main Progress
                mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(100); // Secondary Progress
                mProgress.setMax(100); // Maximum Progress
                mProgress.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
                mProgress.setRotation(0);

                animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgress, "progress", 0, 100);
                animation.setDuration(startTime);
                animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                animation.start();

            }else if (view.getTag() == PAUSE_ICON){
                fab_play_pause.setTag(PLAY_ICON);
                fab_play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp);
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                animation.cancel();
            }
        }
    });

    fab_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timer.setText("0");

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no pause and resume method in countdownTimer class.

When you want to start then you can use

`timer.start()`

and when you want to stop then you can call

`timer.cancel()`

Answer (score 0):

I was writing an app which allowed a runner to enter a distance, a target time and their stride length, and using these would calculate the interval at which to sound a pace tone. I had a start/stop button to allow the runner to toggle the tone on/off. The only way I could get this to work was to cancel the timer activity and then create a new timer. Here's the code which worked for me.

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                if ( ! running ) {

                    running = true;

                    button.setText("STOP");

                    float distance = Float.parseFloat((String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextDistance)).getText().toString());
                    float duration = Float.parseFloat((String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextDuration)).getText().toString());
                    float stepSize = Float.parseFloat((String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextStepSize)).getText().toString());

                    float required = distance / stepSize;
                    float interval = duration * 1000 / required;  

                    ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);

                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP, 150);
                        }
                    }, 0, (long)interval);

                }else{
                    button.setText("START");
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                    timer = new Timer();
                    running = false;
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```